# I accidentally performed chmod 777 -R /

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I know this is a huge security issue etc. but I think it's really weird a lot of my services stopped working (MySQL, SSH, Node) and most importantly sudo probably others aswell. I don't want to reinstall the entire server and I also don't have a ubuntu backup. I don't really care about the security issues, I just want to get the services especially MySQL running again since this is a test server anyway.

Why did chmod make these services unavailabe?
And how do I fix atleast MySQL and sudo?

Comment: check this http://serverfault.com/questions/221447/how-to-repair-restore-ubuntu-10-04-after-sudo-chmod-777

Comment: And just to sum up what the answer was in that other question, save your data and reinstall the OS and your apps.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the havoc caused http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question "why", the answer is that many of these binaries (most notably `ssh` and `sudo`) require the setuid bit to be set, and you cleared it.

Answer (score 1):

Well-written programs that expect to be installed with privileged execution permissions should validate that they have not been started in an insecure configuration, to prevent themselves being used as avenues for damaging a system, and will not run with incorrect permissions or ownership.  Ensuring that this behavior is part of the code is part of the security auditing performed during the release of many major software projects, both open and closed source.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly hack that might get you running again:

1) Find or install a system that's as similar as possible to the system that has issues.

2) Execute a command on that server to output the full path of every file and its permissions. For example:

```
find / | while read F; do ls -lad ${F}; done | cut -f 1,9 -d " " | tee /tmp/log
```

3) Copy the output of that script to the damaged system.

4) Pipe that into a script that sets those permissions. Ignore errors due to non-existing files. For example:

```
cat /tmp/log | while read F; chmod ${F}; done
```